# Efficient way to rename columns from pivot

Tags: python-polars

Currently pivot is joining the "values" column and value from "columns" column as new column name using underscore. Example from data below, new column name = "monthly_qty" + "_" + "product_a"

```
>>> data = pl.DataFrame({"month":["Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar"], "type":["product_a", "product_b"]*3, "monthly_qty":[10,20]*3, "monthly_amt":[5., 8.]*3})
>>> data
shape: (6, 4)
┌───────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ month ┆ type      ┆ monthly_qty ┆ monthly_amt │
│ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ str   ┆ str       ┆ i64         ┆ f64         │
╞═══════╪═══════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ Jan   ┆ product_a ┆ 10          ┆ 5.0         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Jan   ┆ product_b ┆ 20          ┆ 8.0         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Feb   ┆ product_a ┆ 10          ┆ 5.0         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Feb   ┆ product_b ┆ 20          ┆ 8.0         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Mar   ┆ product_a ┆ 10          ┆ 5.0         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Mar   ┆ product_b ┆ 20          ┆ 8.0         │
└───────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
>>> data = data.pivot(index="month", columns="type", values=["monthly_qty", "monthly_amt"])
>>> data
shape: (3, 5)
┌───────┬───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ month ┆ monthly_qty_product_a ┆ monthly_qty_product_b ┆ monthly_amt_product_a ┆ monthly_amt_product_b │
│ ---   ┆ ---                   ┆ ---                   ┆ ---                   ┆ ---                   │
│ str   ┆ i64                   ┆ i64                   ┆ f64                   ┆ f64                   │
╞═══════╪═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ Jan   ┆ 10                    ┆ 20                    ┆ 5.0                   ┆ 8.0                   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Feb   ┆ 10                    ┆ 20                    ┆ 5.0                   ┆ 8.0                   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Mar   ┆ 10                    ┆ 20                    ┆ 5.0                   ┆ 8.0                   │
└───────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

I wish to rename the columns as below, but not sure what is the most efficient way.

- old column = "monthly_qty_product_a"
- new_column = "product_a:monthly_qty"

This is what I can think of now, provided that the number of underscore is fixed.

```
>>> new_cols = {col:col if col=="month" else f"{'_'.join(col.split('_')[2:])}:{'_'.join(col.split('_')[0:2])}"for col in data.columns}
>>> data.rename(new_cols)
shape: (3, 5)
┌───────┬───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ month ┆ product_a:monthly_qty ┆ product_b:monthly_qty ┆ product_a:monthly_amt ┆ product_b:monthly_amt │
│ ---   ┆ ---                   ┆ ---                   ┆ ---                   ┆ ---                   │
│ str   ┆ i64                   ┆ i64                   ┆ f64                   ┆ f64                   │
╞═══════╪═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ Jan   ┆ 10                    ┆ 20                    ┆ 5.0                   ┆ 8.0                   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Feb   ┆ 10                    ┆ 20                    ┆ 5.0                   ┆ 8.0                   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Mar   ┆ 10                    ┆ 20                    ┆ 5.0                   ┆ 8.0                   │
└───────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

This will not work if value column has more than one underscore, e.g. "monthly_growth_pct"

Is there a better way of doing this? Any advice is much appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in [DataFrame.pivot](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html) to control this naming.

I would suggest to modify your long format dataframe (6 x 4) a bit by renaming the column `monthly_qty` to `monthly_qty<CHAR>`, where `<CHAR>` is a character you are quite sure is not present, for example `!`:

```py
data = data.rename({"monthly_qty":"monthly_qty!"})
```

Proceed with the pivot, and then split on `!` in your renaming logic.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, will try that! Thank you